# xpatch + listing + realboxes + mathmode gives wrong spacing

Tags: math-mode, listings, boxes, xpatch

I stumbled upon a problem that was quite hard to reproduce as it seems it required a very specific combination of several packages to make the code compile and yet produce the problem.

The problem is the spacing when using the macro mycmd instead of its expanded version. We get.

[image: result of the compilation]

The code that provides this image in given below. Does someone have any clue of why this is the case and how to correct it ? This would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\lstdefinestyle{def}{
    mathescape,
}

\lstset{style=def}

%To add background color to inline listings
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\lstinline{\Colorbox{gray}\bgroup\appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}}{}{}
\makeatother

%To produce my current use case
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{R=#1}

\begin{document}

%Note that none of the codes below compile without the patch to lstinline

%Wrong spacing
$\mycmd{\lstinline|toto a $b$|}$

%Correct spacing
$R=\lstinline|toto a $b$|$

\end{document}
```

[EDIT]: It seems my problem may not have a general solution. Therefore, is there any way I can achieve something similar to the command sctxa where the parameter may contain inline lsitings ?

```
\newcommand{\semantics}[1]{\llbracket #1 \rrbracket}
\newcommand{\sctxa}[1]{\semantics{#1}_{\alpha_{\mathcal{G}^{\sigma^{abs}}}(\model)}^{a_{var} \leftarrow a,vars}}
```

Comment: Using `\lstinline` in the argument to commands is not really supported.

Comment: Ok, though I still wonder shat is happening in this example... So is there no way I can achieve a macro that adds boilerplate stuff to a formula that may include inline code (see edit for full formula) ?